# ImportError: cannot import name 'Ollama' from 'llama_index.llms' (unknown location)

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, llama-index, mistral-7b, ollama

Getting error while importing Ollama from 'llama_index.llms' in Linux OS.

```
from llama_index.llms import Ollama
response = llm.complete(f"What is code?")
print(response)
```

I installed Ollama from, `curl -fsSL https://ollama.com/install.sh | sh`
Also Installed , `pip3 install llama-index qdrant_client torch transformers`
Its installed successfully.

On running , I am getting -

`ImportError: cannot import name 'Ollama' from 'llama_index.llms' (unknown location)`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue but from https://docs.llamaindex.ai/en/stable/understanding/using_llms/using_llms.html, the import should be:

```
from llama_index.llms.ollama import Ollama
from llama_index.core import Settings

Settings.llm = Ollama(model="llama2", request_timeout=60.0)
```

Still, it doesn't work for me and I suspect there is specific module to install but I don't know which one...

EDIT: found!!!
You have to install llama-index-llms-ollama

Answer (score 0):

You are finding the `ollama` in the wrong place. Instead try using the `ollama-python`

```
pip install ollama
```

Follow the below link of the github and you will find the appropriate documentation for utilizing `ollama` :

https://github.com/ollama/ollama-python

Comment: Thanks , is there a way to get global model variable like "model =. ollama.Model(model='mistral') instead calling the model every time , ollama.generate(model='mistral', prompt='Why is the sky blue?') ?

Comment: I have the same issue and yours answer is related to Ollama 'on its own', it is not related to Ollama in llama-index.

Answer (score 0):

Install the below in virtual environment
`pip install llama-index qdrant_client torch transformers`
`pip install llama-index-llms-ollama`

Sample code :

```
# Just runs .complete to make sure the LLM is listening
from llama_index.llms.ollama import Ollama
from llama_index.core import Settings


llm = Ollama(model="mistral")

response = llm.complete("Who is Laurie Voss? write in 10 words")
print(response)
```